# Can videos recorded using AVFoundation be written directly to the Assets Library?

Tags: video, avfoundation, alassetslibrary

I'm using AVFoundation to record a video to the NSTemporaryDirectory using the below method.

```
[[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self outputFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];
```

Once the recording is stopped the

```
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURLcompletionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)`
```

method is called.

I've noticed that while the video is being written to the photo library from the temp directory, it is being retained there until save is done.

This doesn't make sense to me as it creates the need for double the disk space while the video is being saved. For instance, if I record an hour long 1080p video, the size on disk is 5GB at the end of the recording but goes up to 10GB while saving to the photos library before the temp file is deleted and the disk space is freed up.

Would love to hear your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, its better to temporarily  store the videos to Document-directory as **.mp4**.

Then Save in to  Document-directory and delete it after save.

```
NSString *videoPath = [[self getDirectoryPath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:currentRequest.fileName]] retain];

 NSURL *videoPathURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoPath];                 

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];  

[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoPathURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) { 

       //Delete "videoPath" file from Document directory

}]; 


-(NSString *)getDirectoryPath:(NSString *)fileName {        

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",fileName]];
    return path;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't write the video file directly in Photo library while recording. But you can move the file that you have written in your app's directory(like temp, document, etc) to Photo library instead of copying the file. So you can avoid to have extra space on device in order to save recorded file in Photo library.

I've added the exact API below that can be used to move the recorded files to Photo library.

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
    options.shouldMoveFile = true
    let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
    creationRequest.addResource(with: .video, fileURL: outputFileURL, options: options)
}, completionHandler: { success, error in
    if !success {
        print("Couldn't save the movie to your photo library: \(String(describing: error))")
    }
    cleanup()
   }
)
```

Main part in above example to move the files to photo library is,

```
let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
options.shouldMoveFile = true
```